# Compile error in filter with Slick mapped column type

Tags: scala, slick

I have trouble filtering on a custom type using slick-3.1.1. The following, self contained example, illustrates my problem:

```
object IllustrateSlickQuestion {
  val sqlDriver = slick.driver.PostgresDriver
  import sqlDriver.api._

  trait SomeBaseType {
    def value: Int
  }

  object SomeBaseType {
    def apply(value: Int): SomeBaseType = SomeType(value)
  }

  case class SomeType(value: Int) extends SomeBaseType

  implicit val someBaseTypeMappedColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[SomeBaseType, Int](_.value, SomeBaseType.apply)

  class SomeTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[(SomeBaseType, Option[SomeBaseType])](tag, "my_table") {
    def someColumn = column[SomeBaseType]("some_column")
    def someNullableColumn = column[Option[SomeBaseType]]("some_nullable_column")
    def * = (someColumn, someNullableColumn)
  }

  val someTable = TableQuery[SomeTable]

  // These selects work:
  val compilingSelect1 = someTable.filter(_.someColumn inSet Set(SomeType(42)))
  val compilingSelect2 = someTable.filter(_.someNullableColumn inSet Set(SomeType(42)))

  // Does not compile:
  //   [error] type mismatch;
  //   [error]   found   : IllustrateSlickQuestion.SomeType
  //   [error]   required: slick.lifted.Rep[?]
  //   [error]    val brokenSelect1 = someTable.filter(_.someColumn === SomeType(42))
  val brokenSelect1 = someTable.filter(_.someColumn === SomeType(42))

  // Does not compile either:
  //  [error] see above
  val brokenSelect2 = someTable.filter(_.someNullableColumn === SomeType(42))
}
```

This problem goes away if I use `SomeType` instead of `SomeBaseType` in my definitions and in the `MappedColumnType`. That however is not an option in the code I really care about, since there `SomeBaseType` represents an enumeration. I'm therefore stuck with using `inSet` instead of `===` as a workaround.

Am I doing anything wrong, or is this a bug in Slick?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure on the exact reason why this happens. I think it has to do with having ambiguous implicit conversions in scope (both to Rep[SomeBaseType] and to Rep[Option[SomeBaseType]]). So the compiler doesn't know which to choose (and thus chooses neither). But I could be wrong. I do have some workarounds for you:

```
// Adding a type annotation to the filter:
val fixedSelect1 = someTable.filter(_.someColumn === (SomeType(42):SomeBaseType))

// Using a helper method:
def query(someType: Rep[SomeBaseType]) =
  someTable.filter(_.someNullableColumn === someType)

query(SomeType(42))

// With compiled queries
val query = Compiled { (someType: Rep[SomeBaseType]) =>
  someTable.filter(_.someNullableColumn === someType)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! I don't really understand the magic that is going on in the signatures of `inSet` and `===`, but I guess that the covariance of  `Traversable` in `def inSet[R](seq: Traversable[B1])(implicit om: o#to[Boolean, R])` might be one of the reasons why it works there without a type annotation. I'm wondering if `def === [P2, R](e: Rep[P2])(implicit om: o#arg[B1, P2]#to[Boolean, R])` could be modified so that `===` behaves more intuitive.

Answer (score -1):

This is a Scala issue, not a Slick issue. Extending a case class from an object is not recommended. Your sample code does not show how the `value` property of the case class is used. Did you mean to override the base class `value` property? If so, then you need to write:

```
case class SomeType(override val value: Int) extends SomeBaseType
```

However, you will encounter issues. You may find that an ADT is preferable to using `Enumerator`:

```
sealed trait MyEnum
trait EnumValue1 extends MyEnum
trait EnumValue2 extends MyEnum
trait EnumValue3 extends MyEnum
```

Then you might be able to write something like this (not tested):

```
case class SomeType(myEnum: MyEnum) extends AnyVal with MappedTo[Int]
```

My preference is to use a Java enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    EnumValue1 , EnumValue2, EnumValue3
}
```

And then write:

```
case class SomeType(myEnum: MyEnum) extends AnyVal with MappedTo[Int]
```

Comment: Hmm, I've never heard that case classes should not implement traits; quite the opposite, this is common practice, as popular examples like `Option` or the implementation of `List` show. Also, the `override` keyword you are mentioning is completely optional in the code we are talking about. Last but not least, the enumeration I'm referring to is an ADT just like yours (enhanced by https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum#slick-integration). As for falling back to Java enums: I already have a workaround, that I would prefer in this case.

Comment: Mattias notice the override val in my sample code. Anyway, you solved this somehow so you should either post the answer and mark it as such tomorrow, or delete the question

Comment: The object you are referring to is the companion object of trait directly above it. This trait is it that I extend....

Comment: As for `override`: This shouldn't make any difference, but I just checked it to be absolutely sure! Since I do not yet know if I'm doing something wrong or this is a bug in Slick this question is not answered and I won't delete it also.